# Changing a column value in pandas if value in other column matches string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I'm a beginner to Pandas and I'm having a little trouble getting something to work.

My task is that I was given a dataframe as follows:

| AnimalID | Pet Name | Pet Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Whiskers | Cat |
| 2 | Charlie | Dog |
| 3 | Spot | Dog |
| 4 | Honey | Cat |

What I'm attempting to do is add a '+' symbol to the end of the ID if the pet type is a dog.

My solution was to iterate through each row using iterrows() and check if the Pet Type Matches, and if it does, change the ID in that row. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_excel('AnimalList.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({'AnimalID':[1,2,3,4], 'Pet Name':['Whiskers', 'Charlie', 'Spot', 'Honey'], 'Pet Type':['Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat']})
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Pet Type'].eq('Dog').any():
        row['AnimalID'] = df['AnimalID'].astype(str) + '+'

df
```

The dataframe is printing without error, but is there any reason that nothing is changing? I have to be missing something obvious. Thank you.

Comment: I quite heavily edited your question to make it reproducible, correcting even probable typos in the code. But even once that done, there is no way this code could have ever run "without error". `iterrows` returns pairs `(num, object)`. And  line `row['AnimalID'] = df['AnimalID']` cannot mean anything (a single row.AnimalID is computed from a whose series of it)

Comment: Even correcting what I cannot edit (since that would be changing code, not correcting probable typos), that is `for i,row in df.iterrows():` to take into account what iterrows returns; `row['AnimalID']=str(row['AnimalID'])+'+'`, `if row['Pet Type']=='Dog'` (it seems that you have tried to work directly on dataframe, and some of your code, like `.eq` or `.astype`, `.any()` would make sense on columns, not on single values), your problem is that row is not always a "view" of a row. (but sometimes is) When you change it, it doesn't always affect the dataframe.

Comment: See last sentence of [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Comment: The correct way is, anyway, to never ever iterate rows (unless there is no other way, obviously. But there almost always is one). You got 2 answers that work without iterating rows. But if you really need to, in this case, it probably would have been easier to use `.loc`. `df.loc[i, 'AnimalID'] = str(df.loc[i, 'AnimalID'])+'+'` does affect the dataframe. Bad idea again (the good idea is one of the 2 answers you got). But at least it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to column `AnimalID`. Its values will be replaced where the condition is `False`, so we will need to check [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to add `+` for each row where this column equals `Dog`.

```
df['AnimalID'] = df['AnimalID'].where(df['Pet Type'].ne('Dog'), 
                                      df['AnimalID'].astype(str) + '+')

print(df)

  AnimalID  Pet Name Pet Type
0        1  Whiskers      Cat
1       2+   Charlie      Dog
2       3+      Spot      Dog
3        4     Honey      Cat
```

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it using mask

```
# when condition is true, add + to the ID
df['AnimalID']=(df['AnimalID'].mask(df['Pet Type'].eq('Dog'), 
                                    df['AnimalID'].astype(str) + ('+')))
df
```

```
    AnimalID    Pet Name    Pet Type
0          1    Whiskers    Cat
1         2+    Charlie     Dog
2         3+    Spot        Dog
3          4    Honey       Cat
```